# Error reading varchar field db2 with jpa

Tags: java, jpa, utf-8, eclipselink, varchar

I'm getting an error every time I try to fill an attribute from my Javaclass with the information stored in a Db2 table. Only the String Attribute is causing trouble.

I use JPA (EclipseLink) 
The Field with the Problem is "name1" and is declared in my class as a String variable.

The error only happens with this Entity, getting the information from other Entities does not throw exceptions.

This is my prinstack:

```
sun.io.MalformedInputException
at sun.io.ByteToCharUTF8.convert(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.v.a(v.java:16)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gc.a(gc.java:1803)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gc.n(gc.java:503)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gc.P(gc.java:1723)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ul.e(ul.java:1270)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ul.getObject(ul.java:1252)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabasePlatform.getObjectFromResultSet(DatabasePlatform.java:1344)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.getObject(DatabaseAccessor.java:1300)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.fetchRow(DatabaseAccessor.java:1075)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processResultSet(DatabaseAccessor.java:768)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:655)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1991)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2738)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2691)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:495)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1168)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:403)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1215)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1793)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1775)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1740)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:469)
at de.basler.archivierung.db2.dao.fi.Kreditoren_SaldenListeDAO.findView(Kreditoren_SaldenListeDAO.java:39)
at de.basler.archivierung.service.view.fi.Service_Kreditoren_SaldenListe.findViewInhalt(Service_Kreditoren_SaldenListe.java:19)
at de.basler.archivierung.web.controller.fi.ControllerFIKreditoren.search(ControllerFIKreditoren.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:74)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:365)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1656)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:862)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:42)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is the type in the database, and what does the driver return for it when using JDBC directly?  The driver seems to not be able to convert the data in the field to a CharUTF8 format, so you might need to check the field type and data in the database and map it to something else instead.

Answer (score 1):

The type in the database is Varchar. Using JBDC directly, I also get an Exception
I Use the same Driver to connect to other DB and never had problems. Could the driver have problems with the encoding from the DB?

The stacktrace when I use directly JDBC:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: [jcc][t4][1065][12306][3.53.70] Bedingung java.io.CharConversionException abgefangen. Details finden Sie im angehängten Element der Throwable-Klasse. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bd.a(bd.java:660)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bd.a(bd.java:60)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bd.a(bd.java:112)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gc.a(gc.java:1807)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gc.n(gc.java:503)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gc.D(gc.java:1143)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ul.getDouble(ul.java:806)
at de.basler.archivierung.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 34
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.v.a(v.java:19)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gc.a(gc.java:1803)
... 4 more
Caused by: sun.io.MalformedInputException
at sun.io.ByteToCharUTF8.convert(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.v.a(v.java:16)
... 5 more
```

"This should be added to the question instead of added as an answer."

Sorry for that.

I have isolated the field, which is causing problems. The column contains the name of corporations. An example "Düsseldorf". Some Strings could have czech Character. DB coding Page 1401.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This should be added to the question instead of added as an answer.  The query is returning data that the driver doesn't like.  You will have to isolate the data that is causing the problem to determine what is going wrong.  Try finding a particular row that can't be read and posting the string data - it seems related to a character conversion of non-UTF-8 data that you may have to go to the driver docs to solve

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problema using this

```
@Column(name = "evt_description", length=2000)
String description;
```

in my case the problem has that description has size greater than 255